# What is the reading of おー?

Tags: readings, interjections

I'm going to guess おこころ and then prepare to get laughed at (笑).

Here is the tweet in which it appeared:

https://twitter.com/tsukune_koubou/status/1525719820133875712?s=20&t=6UUD76jtLHslpLOvgYfJxA

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: If this is in something like a text message then I’d assume it just means “Ooh! ”, in which case you wouldn’t normally vocalize the emoji…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just おー, maybe with an intonation that expresses excited/impressed/encouraging feelings when spoken.

Sometimes emojis are used in place of nouns, as in に乗ります for でんしゃにのります, but I don't think this is one of them in almost any imaginable context.